# API indexedDB- Showing date in format DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: html, date, indexeddb

I have an html with a form where I colect data type: text, radio and date.
When I pick up the date, I can see the format is dd.mm.yyyy. 
Then I went to see the way the date is save and in the BD I see:
Object
date
:
"2017-09-12"

Now my question is, is there a way to show in the html the date in the format dd-mm-YYYY or to save the date in dd-mm-yyyy instead.
Thank you so much in advance
Marcela

Answer (score 1):

You can store date objects in indexedDB. A date object is not concerned with how it is displayed, and does not provide or store properties related to a date's format.

If you are viewing the set of objects in an object store using a browser's devtools panel, date values are displayed according to some built-in setting in devtools. The way dates are displayed in a devtools view of an object store does not reflect how dates are actually stored. Dates are actually stored as simple numbers. There is a big difference between how a value is stored and how it is displayed.

Therefore, so long as you property store dates as dates (not as strings that look like dates), then you can choose how to display a date after retrieving it from indexedDB. You make this decision outside of using indexedDB, because this is not a concern of indexedDB. indexedDB is only concerned with storing values.

So, when writing code:

1) When saving an object with a date property to indexedDB, ensure the date property is of type date.
2) When getting an object from indexedDB, get its date property, and then convert the date property into a string in a format that you prefer.

Here is some really ugly pseudo-code to help you:

```
// This function accepts a date value as input, and then returns a 
// string representing the formatted date
function formatDate(dateValue) {

  // Get the parts of the date

  var dayOfMonthNumber = dateValue.getDate();
  // The +1 is because January is 0, but we want it to be 1
  var monthNumber = dateValue.getMonth() + 1;
  var yearNumber = dateValue.getYear();

  // Compose a string of the parts

  var dateString = '';
  dateString += dayOfMonthNumber;
  dateString += '-';
  dateString += monthNumber;
  dateString += '-';
  dateString += yearNumber;

  return dateString;
}


myObject.myDateProperty = new Date('1.2.3');
saveObjectInIndexedDB(myObject);

var myObject = getObjectFromIndexedDB();
var myDatePropertyAsADate = myObject.myDateProperty;
var myFormattedDateString = formatDate(myDatePropertyAsDate);

var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
myElement.textContent = myFormattedDateString;
```